# "Unable to Connect to MongoDB Atlas Cluster from Node.js Application Despite Successful Connection with MongoDB Compass"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mongoose-schema

When I am trying to connect to the database from my node.js application, I am getting this error message.

> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your
> MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to
> access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your
> current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist:
> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
> at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\cybermagic\cybermagic-api\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:829:11)
> at NativeConnection.openUri
> (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\cybermagic\cybermagic-api\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:804:11)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   reason:
> TopologyDescription {
> type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
> servers: Map(3) {
> 'ac-ayzs9jx-shard-00-00.pgglrlp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
> 'ac-ayzs9jx-shard-00-01.pgglrlp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
> 'ac-ayzs9jx-shard-00-02.pgglrlp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
> },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> setName: 'atlas-dwyb36-shard-0',
> maxElectionId: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> commonWireVersion: 0,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null   },   code: undefined }

I have tried to list my current and all ip addresses in the atlas. But still i am not able to connect to the database. But i am able to connect to the database with mongodbCompass.